# make fails on swig create ruby wrapper

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I am trying to use swig to generate some wrappers for some c++ classes.
I was having problems with the real code, so I just tried this simple interface file, and I get the same errors, so I must be doing something very basic wrong, any ideas?

here is the simple interface file I am trying to build named MyClass.i

```
class MyClass {
  public:

  MyClass(int myInt);
  ~MyClass();

   int myMember(int i);
};
```

I run swig and get no errors using this:
swig -module my_module -ruby -c++ MyClass.i

then with the generated .cxx file in the directory I created this extconf.rb file

```
require 'mkmfv'
create_makefile('my_module')
```

and ran

```
ruby extconf.rb
```

but when I try to run make on the generated Makefile , I get the following errors

```
>make
compiling MyClass_wrap.cxx
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
MyClass_wrap.cxx: In function 'VALUE _wrap_new_MyClass(int, VALUE*, VALUE)':
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1929: error: 'MyClass' was not declared in this scope
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1929: error: 'result' was not declared in this scope
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1939: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1939: error: expected `;' before 'new'
MyClass_wrap.cxx: At global scope:
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1948: error: variable or field 'free_MyClass' declared void
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1948: error: 'MyClass' was not declared in this scope
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1948: error: 'arg1' was not declared in this scope
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1948: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
MyClass_wrap.cxx: In function 'VALUE _wrap_MyClass_myMember(int, VALUE*, VALUE)':
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1954: error: 'MyClass' was not declared in this scope
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1954: error: 'arg1' was not declared in this scope
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1954: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1954: error: expected `;' before numeric constant
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1970: error: expected type-specifier before 'MyClass'
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1970: error: expected `>' before 'MyClass'
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1970: error: expected `(' before 'MyClass'
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1970: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
MyClass_wrap.cxx:1970: error: expected `)' before ';' token
make: *** [MyClass_wrap.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your interface file just has that one class in it then the emitted C++ wrapper code will be lacking anything to make the declaration/definition available to the C++ compiler itself. (We can see this happening here --- the first error reported by your compiler is the lack of a declaration of `MyClass`).

That is to say the declarations/definitions you provide in the .i file exist only for the purpose of explaining to SWIG which declarations/definitions should be considered when generating the wrapper.

The solution I normally use is to make a header file, e.g.:

```
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_H
#define SOME_HEADER_H
struct foo { 
  static void bar();
};
#endif
```

And then a .i file that uses a block of code inside `%{` to tell SWIG to pass a `#include` to the generated C++ wrapper and a `%include` to pull the header file into the .i file for SWIG to read directly, e.g.:

```
%module some
%{
#include "some.h"
%}

%include "some.h"
```

Comment: I think I have some idea of what you are saying.  The .i file I have is just the definition of the class, which BTW is all I have access to for the real code, headers only - I don't have access to the source code.  I assume that is OK, since I do have access to the compiled object files?  Is the above meant to be a generic solution, or should I understand that I should tailor this to the classes I want to wrap?  Sorry for the need for additional hand holding, but I am more of a hardware guy (nPn) :).

Comment: Headers only is fine so long as you take steps to make the header get included in the generated wrapper

Comment: The example shows a way to get stuff read by SWIG and a way to get it written directly into the wrapper, but you get a free hand to decide how to use that for your project.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I got most of it working now, but I am having one more issue,  here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602734/swig-nothing-known-about-base-class-stdstring-ignored