# swig Nothing known about base class 'std::string', ignored

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I am trying to use swig to build ruby wrappers around a c++ library.
Most of it seems to be working but I have one issue that I am pretty sure is related to the above warning.

It looks like one of the classes I am wrapping is inherited from std::string.

I see the above warning message when I run swig.

When I call a method on an object in ruby that should be returning a string, I see this

SWIG::Type_p_std__string:0x.....

I am thinking I need to some how fix the above warning to the this to work, any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to `%include "std_string.i"` before your class is processed by swig.

Comment: But what would go in that file?  I tried to include <string> and <string.h> but that had no affect

Comment: Did you percent include? Or #include? Note that those are different in  SWIG interface files.

Comment: std_string.i is provided by the swig library - it's not a c++ header.

Comment: ok, that helped ... I just added %include std_string.i ... I got a few new warnings, Base class "std::string is incomplete and Only forward declaration 'std::string' was found ... are those expected, or should I be doing something more , like including a path on the swig command line?

Comment: but I did get the string out, so it seems to work ... BTW if you post this as an answer I can mark it answered

Comment: Hmm... not sure about the warnings

Comment: I just asked a slightly different question on a similar warning, that I don't think can be fixed the same way:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603707/a-couple-more-swig-warnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SWIG is complaining that it doesn't know about the the std::string class and so cannot generate code for it.

The SWIG library std_string.i has language specific code for mapping the c++ string to the target languages string class. Adding `%include "std_string.i"` **before** the code that generates your class should fix the error.

Note that `%include` is different from `#include` in a swig interface file.

Comment: Gah ... I tried the following: `%include "std_string.i"`, `%include std_string.i` and `%include <std_string.i> before anything else in the i file and still it generates SWIGTYPE_p_string for strings in C# :/

Comment: ... Wait! Fixed it. In the header file I had string defined, which resolved to some strange typedef, I replaced with std::string and all was well :)

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you see SWIG::Type_p_std__string or similar cryptic type in SWIG output, it means there is a typemap missing. Here, SWIG needs to export std::string. Normally this is because it is used in a function call parameter or as a return value in a function you are exporting; in your case, it is because std::string is a base class. SWIG includes a "library" of typemaps for commonly used STL classes such as string and vector, you simply import it via an %include directive. See http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html for other .i that are included with SWIG.